# How can I identify the current version of Weblogic Server

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic

I have a situation where the same lines of code must run on both Weblogic 11g (10.3.5) and Weblogic 12.  This is while we (slowly) work on upgrading.

Unfortunately, Weblogic 11 seems not to set a certain request attribute properly (FORWARD_QUERY_STRING), so I need a slightly different set of instructions to perform a certain task.  The WLS 11 version throws an exception on WLS 12, and vice versa.

My question is: is there a way that, at runtime, I can identify the Weblogic version, and so run the appropriate lines?

Answer (score 1):

`ServletContext.getServerInfo()` will tell server information on which it is running.

**References:**

[ServletContext.getServerInfo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServerInfo%28%29)

Comment: Thanks.  Although I had to search around to get the servlet context too, as this check is in a method that receives an `HttpServletRequest` as its only parameter. I will have to use `request.getSession().getServletContext().getServerInfo()`: ugh.

Answer (score 0):

We set environment variables for our various WebLogic servers so that runtime code can react to the specific version. Set this variable in the server startup script.

Comment: Nice, but we've got a bunch of different servers, and modifying the environment is not practical.